# How do I import all the referenced libraries to my folder in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I pack the code in Java in JAR form, will those referenced libraries in Eclipse be packed inside also?

I have run into a tutorial that use import > general > file system to import JAR files instead of external JAR files. Are there any differences?

Comment: What do you mean by packed? Are we talking about the case when you export a jar file?

Comment: yes! that is what i mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you export a runnable jar file (using the Export wizard), there is an option to include all dependencies. This is not the default, and it requires some class-loading magic (which Eclipse takes care of under the hood), but if you do that, Eclipse does include all jar files your code depends on and you end up with a standalone jar file. If you create a normal jar file (runnable or not), no dependencies are included.

Comment: I have run into a tutorial that use import > general > file system  to import jar instead of external jar. Is there any differences?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can right click on Project --> Property --> Java buildpath --> and select library tab and select "Add jar" or "Add External java " into lib folder...

So, it is a very good way to put all libraries into the `lib` folder in your project.

Or you also can add a new reference library at a time when you create your new project.